# Parsing json response from httpwebresponse into listView data binding windows

Tags: c#, json, listview, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8.1

I am making a http post as follows

```
public async Task<string> HttppostJson()
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("URL") as HttpWebRequest;

        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";

        string post = "postData";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post.ToString());

        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        //Write data into a stream
        using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, null))
        {
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        // Pick up the response:

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This gives me a JSON string as output. A small part of it is as follows

```
{
  "id":20,
  "title":"Testing after phase 2 is shifted to server",
  "from":"Administrator",
  "sendername":"ABX",
  "day":"Tuesday",
  "dateofMonth":"20th",
  "month":"May",
  "year":2014,
  "date":"Tuesday, 20th May, 2014",
  "content":"Ready. Set. Go"
```

}

There are 19 more such blocks refering to each "id". I want to deserialize the objects and populate them in a list view , only the "title" and "from" from all 20 notices should be seen in the listView. More id's will be added later so I want to make the listView dynamic which should include the new added id's and corresponding "title" and "from". So the listview should look like this

```
Title= "title"_corresponding_to_id
subtitle= "from"_correspondin_to_id

Title= "title"_corresponding_to_id
subtitle= "from"_correspondin_to_id

Title= "title"_corresponding_to_id
subtitle= "from"_correspondin_to_id
                ..
                .. 
                ..
```

I am new to Windows app development. SO needed a little help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Movie class. 
Then you can use newtonsoft's Json.NET library and use JObject class.

You just save json response into a string and then get values from JObject and add it to list.

```
    string json = someJsonText
    JObject response = JObject.Parse(json);
    List<Movie> list = new List<Movie>();
    Movie first = new Movie();
    first.Title = response.GetValue("title");
    list.Add(first);
```

And do that in foreach or for sentence to get, create and save all the movies.

Comment: I am doing it like this : var resp = await HttppostJson();

            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp);

            foreach (var o in obj)
            {
                List<Notice> items = new List<Notice>();
                items.Add(new Notice { title = o["title"], from = o["from"] });
            }  But it only displays the "title" and "from" corresponding to "id"=0. Any idea?